# addEventListener submit and jQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-events

I have form:

```
<form id="form1" class="f_class">
<input type="button" class="jq-button" value="jq-button"/>
</form>
```

And js code:

```
var f=document.getElementById("form1");
f.addEventListener("submit", function(){alert("addEventListener_submit");},false);
$(".jq-button").click(function(){$("#form1").submit();});
```

([Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/upihuj/3/edit))

When I click to jq-button alert does not show.
Why?

**UPDATE**

I have external js code, which use `addEventListener`, and I can't change it. But in my code I want use jQuery submit. Can I combined them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just correct it to:

`<input type="submit" class="jq-button" value="jq-button"/>`

Answer (score 0):

$().submit() triggers the jquery submit event and not the eventlisterner. I would have written it with jQuery all of the binding of events like:

```
var f = $("#form1");
f.on("submit", function() { // on requires jquery 1.7+
    alert("submit");
});
$(".jq-button").on("click", (function(e) {
    $(this).closest("form").trigger("submit");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

### Edit:

you **could** do something like:

```
var f=document.getElementById("form1");

f.addEventListener("submit", function(){
    alert("addEventListener_submit");
},false);

$(".jq-button").click(function(){
    var c = $(this),
        cc = c.clone().attr("type","submit");
    c.replaceWith(cc);
    cc.click();
});
```

if you can´t change the HTML markup.

Comment: Would you mind if I ask whether jquery submit event differs from the pure DOM event?

Comment: when you try to trigger an event in jquery you are refering it to its jquery event binding (look at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js on how they are binding it with ´add´ method

Comment: I have external js code, which use addEventListener, and i can't change it. But in my code i want use jquery. Can i combined them?

Comment: @DeeRain easiest way is to change the HTML markup that Ch4rAss has done.